# Is it possible to use PySimpleGUI and Tkinter together to create a user interface in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, widget, pysimplegui

How can I merge a PySimpleGUI code inside a Tkinter code such that after running, both of them shall appear on the same screen?

Example: I want to use the Text and Button which are written in PySimpleGUI, under a frame which is made using Tkinter. How can I do that?

My Code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [[sg.Text("PySimpleGUI Window")], [sg.Button("PySimpleGUI Button")]]

window = sg.Window("PySimpleGUI Window", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "PySimpleGUI Button":

        break


window.close()
```

Comment: Just try. Personally I doubt: both uses completely different libraries, so one has no idea on what the other application will do (including redrawing). Try not to mix things. It makes code more difficult, unmaintainable, and it cause all problems.

Comment: Not something I would recommend.  The documentation discusses accessing the internals, but nothing quite like you're after.  Just use tkinter if you want to write tkinter code.  Otherwise, convert your tkinter code to PySimpleGUI.  Sound like an unusual project that might not fit PySimpleGUI.

Comment: Why don't you use the *Frame* element of PySimpleGUI?